# Base Plunker for Angular2

Tags: angular, plunker

Can anybody provide me a basic Pluker for 'angular2 final' having couple of routes and 2(or 3) level nested modules?

(I have created my project using angular-cli & I'm just importing child modules in parent modules in order to use child routes and child components)

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html

Answer (score 0):

Working Plunker from angular.io with routing.

https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html